# Getting ID's from playlist through Spotify API

Tags: python, json, api, flask, spotify

My problem is that I can not figure out a way to get the playlist ID or the track ID. Here is a snipped of the code.  The json_response is correct I am just going about parsing through it very wrong.  I have changed my code around from trying to get a playlist ID to trying to get a song id, here currently I am trying to get a track id.  But before I had code trying to get the playlist ID and I was working through the son wrong as well.

```
token = getAccessToken(clientID, clientSecret)
response =requests.get(query,
headers={"Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Authorization":"Bearer " + token})
    
json_response = response.json()
head_one = "<h1/>"
head_two = "</h2"
id = json_response.id
return id
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this syntax

```
#...

id = json_response["id"]
return id
```

If that does not work I suspect you still need to convert to JSON yourself

```
import json

#...
json_response = json.loads(response.json)
id = json_response["id"]
return id
```

Please let me know if it works